# How to make use of Entity-Relationship diagrams to model mathematical expressions?

Tags: database, database-design, math, data-modeling, entity-relationship

I am a newbie in Entity-Relationship diagrams (ERD) and have some difficulty in trying to come up with the diagram/model for the following problem - I don't even have a clue on where to start. Is this even possible? Any advice or solution would be greatly appreciated.

> How can the ERD be used to generically
>   model mathematical expressions (plus,
>   minus, multiply and divide) taking
>   into account of the following
>   precedence in which the expression is
>   to be evaluated.
>
> - Expressions in brackets must be evaluated first (Note that brackets can be nested within other brackets up to an unlimited depth).
> - Multiply and divide must be evaluated    before plus and minus
> - Multiply and divide must be evaluated    from left to right
> - Plus and minus must be evaluated from    left to right
>
> Please indicate the attributes found
>   in each entity as depicted in your
>   proposed solution/diagram.

Comment: It's certainly possible (although I suspect that the answer I would give would not be the expected answer based on the wording of the prompt).  You just need to come up with what the "things" are.  Those are your entities.  And then figure out how they're related to each other.  Those are your relationships.  Then you can figure out what attributes the things should have.

Comment: Ehhhhh ... I had that one as homework ...

Answer (score 2):

But who gave you this? A teacher? For real?

ER-Diagrams are not made for this! Does your teacher know what ER-Diagrams are? For this kind of modelling there are Activity and other diagrams.

But for the beginning I see a recursive relation:

```
Expression ----inside----> Bracket ------->cotains------->Bracket
```

Expression is an entity,Bracket is ONE an entity. Inside and contains are relations. Bracket has a relation which gos to itself again. Dont draw two entities.. and so on....

Just look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:ER_Diagram_MMORPG.png
Expression is equal to Character in the graphic, and Bracket is equal to Account...

Answer (score 0):

This is probably simpler than you think if you are willing to think of all expressions as "bracketed" and think of toyr storage as an expression tree.  It helps that all operations are left-to-right.  Just consider a recursive design in which each operand can be the id of another expression (recursive) or a literal (basecase).

You aren't going to have much of an ER diagram per se.

```
Expression: id, leftOperand, rightOperand, operator

You may or may not want an operator table.  Depends on what you foresee being done in database and what you foresee being done in application code.
Operators: id, symbol,
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were going to express expressions in the form of tables, I would use nested sets to express the fact that some operands are themselves expressions.

I regard operator precedence as syntactic sugar, making it easier to write formulas in text based programming languages.  I think making the precedence explicit in an internal model is probably more worthwhile than having precedence rules for disambiguation.

As to the detailed design, I'll leave that as homework.

Comment: yes, but in real-world you will never model something like this as an ER-Diagram. This is going against the rules. Its more of an behaviourial diagram, like use-case diagrams or activity diagrams.

Comment: Dave, in part I agree. I certainly have never been tempted to render an expression as an ERD. But there are plenty of other questions in here that are examples of things I would not do. So there could be method in the madness.  Certainly there might be value in expressing process in terms of data.  And if you have decided to do that, data analysis might be the next logical step.

Comment: After thinking about it, here's an application that might lead to creating an ERD for an expression. Let's say you wanted to create a tool like the ones from Emarcadero and others that let you specify a database interactively, and store your data model (in a metadatabase), and eventually can convert your work into a series of CREATE commands, (CREATE DATABASE, CREATE TABLE, etc.) that go into a database creation script. If you want to include CREATE VIEW, you have to model a SELECT. And the elements of the select list are experessions. Now you need an ERD of an expression for data analysis.